# Can't find whl when using local pypi repository

Tags: python, pip, nexus

I'm trying to use a local nexus pypi repository to store my python whls but cannot download them successfully using PIP.

Nexus is running on a machine with the ip `W.X.Y.Z`

and, via the web connection it shows my test repository

```
http://W.X.Y.Z:8081/#browse/browse/components:pypi-internal-test
```

If I select one of the whls it displays it shows a path of

```
Path    packages/tradeloader/1.1.0/tradeloader-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

On my remote machine where I would like to install this whl I use the following command:

```
pip install --trusted-host W.X.Y.Z -i http://W.X.Y.:8081/repository/pypi-internal-test/packages tradeloader
```

It fails with the following

```
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'Py_UNICODE_SIZE' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Collecting tradeloader
  1 location(s) to search for versions of tradeloader:
  * http://W.X.Y.Z:8081/repository/pypi-internal-test/packages/tradeloader/
  Getting page http://W.X.Y.Z:8081/repository/pypi-internal-test/packages/tradeloader/
  Starting new HTTP connection (1): W.X.Y.Z
  "GET /repository/pypi-internal-test/packages/tradeloader/ HTTP/1.1" 401 0
User for W.X.Y.Z:8081: <<My user>>
Password:
  "GET /repository/pypi-internal-test/packages/tradeloader/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1814
  Could not fetch URL http://W.X.Y.Z:8081/repository/pypi-internal-test/packages/tradeloader/: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://W.X.Y.Z:8081/repository/pypi-internal-test/packages
/tradeloader/ - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tradeloader (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for tradeloader
```

If I try and download the whl via the browser using

```
http://X.X.Y.Z:8081/repository/pypi-all/packages/tradeloader/1.1.0/tradeloader-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

the whl comes down fine but, of course, I'm being very specific about what I want there and would like pip to allow me to just ask for the most recent

I have been looking at this for a while and cannot see where I'm going wrong. Would anybody be able to help?

**Edit: The following web page has the answer**

[Unable to install PyPi package](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000572308-Unable-to-install-PyPi-package)

Comment: try `--extra-index-url http://W.X.Y.:8081/repository/pypi-internal-test/packages` instead of `-i`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. the --extra-index-url returned exactly the same

Comment: Could you move your wheel to the base folder of your package on your local pypi instead of placing it in version directory . I.e try `packages/tradeloader/tradeloader-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` instead of your current folder structure.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do that. The package is put in that location by setup.py so I assumed that location would be correct. Does it look wrong to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you configured pip.conf according to these instructions?

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/PyPI+Repositories+-+NXRM+3#PyPIRepositories-NXRM3-ConfiguringPyPIClientTools

Comment: I read that page when I set the nexus repo up but didn't think it had any relevance. I use setup tools to install my whl - bdist_wheel upload -r pypi (pypi is configured in my .pypirc file). I don't have a repository group defined as the grouping is done within Nexus, although in the example above I was referencing the test repository directly. Does it sound like I have missed something out?

Comment: Ok. I finally figured it out and to answer you, no I hadn't got my pip.conf file set correctly. Your answer enabled me to find a more detailed description of the setup. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide a well set pip.conf?